# Python Mongoengine - get the type of a document attribute

Tags: python, mongoengine

Is there a simple way to get the type of a given attribute of a document ?
I have the name of the attribute, and I want to check if it is a number. For example, if the input is the string "price" I should return True, because the values would be numbers.

For the moment I'm trying to fetch the first document with a not null value in the given attribute, but i'm not succeeding at this, and I wonder if there is a more direct way to get the type of the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your best chance is to check the type of the Document fields and maintain a mapping between field type (e.g StringField) and actual type (e.g str).

The following should give you an idea on how to achieve that:

```
class TestDocument(Document):
    s = StringField()
    i = IntField()

assert isinstance(TestDocument.s, StringField)

def get_field_type(docCls, attr):
    field = getattr(docCls, attr)
    mapping = {StringField: str, IntField: int}
    return mapping[type(field)]

assert get_field_type(TestDocument, 's') == str
assert get_field_type(TestDocument, 'i') == int
```